# Updates for custom module not showing in update.php list

Tags: updating

I've created a custom module for my Drupal 7 website, under `sites/all/modules/custom/tm_general` which has the following updates in the `tm_general.install` (please see image attached).

The site is being installed from scratch, meaning the DB is empty when installing. After installation, I have enabled the custom module through the UI.

The problem I'm encountering is that when visiting `mysite.local/update.php` the updates won't show up. It says `No pending updates.`

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot in advanced!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are freshly enabling the module, all updates will be applied by default.
If you are upgrading that module from previous module to new one..then you will see those upgrade messages on /update.php

Comment: It makes sense, however the updates haven't been applied when enabling the module. I have tried to move the code inside the `hook_enable` to see if that made a difference but it didn't :(

Comment: _however the updates haven't been applied when enabling the module_ that's correct - updates are only for updating modules. For new installs, `hook_enable` and `hook_install` should be used as appropriate to make sure the database is in the same state as it would be for old versions of the module that had been updated

Comment: Thank you @Clive - using the `hook_unable` solved the problem for the newly added module in the site

Answer (score -1):

The 'system' table in your db contains the current "version" of modules, so I would check there first.

Also, if these modules are dependencies, you can just include them in your module.info [(writing module .info files in Drupal 7)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x) by simply adding

```
dependencies[] = devel
dependencies[] = views
```

and so on.